# Mit app inventor camcorder auto recording

Tags: java, app-inventor

I am making Mit App Inventor application with feature of auto video recording using back camera.
I need help regarding auto video recording for 5 seconds.
Need your suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no such functionality available in MIT App Inventor, but you could write your own extension and create some blocks yourself...

more information about how to create an extension see the [App Inventor Extensions document](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/extensions.html), however that will be more advanced and will require some Java skills...